# Copy paste range of cells for every row called xxxx

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

[image]

I have this worksheet that I want to move (by copy and paste) range of weeks as well as every row called Plan. Below is a simple Script that I'm using but I would like to create of loop of it if possible?

Basiclly I want to copy and paste range from column E to Column O. Paste it in column D and then go back to column O and remove any value that is there.

```
enter code here

<Range("E2:O2").Select    
Selection.Copy    
Range("D2").Select    
ActiveSheet.Paste    
Range("O2").Select    
Selection.ClearContents    


Range("E4:O4").Select    
Selection.Copy    
Range("D4").Select    
ActiveSheet.Paste    
Range("O4").Select    
Selection.ClearContents>
```

Comment: SO whenever "Plan" is in column B in effect you want to cut E:O and paste in D:N?

Comment: Yes that is correct. For every "Plan" in column B I want to copy E:O and paste it in D:N. Do you know if cut works eqully as copy?I have tried move but then all my formulas get N/A, so move doen't work. I found copy paste to not interfere with my forumulas but maybe cut and past works eqully well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cut Paste

### Cut Version

```
Sub CutPaste()

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"      ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFirstS As Variant = "E"          ' Source First Column Letter/Number
    Const cLastS As Variant = "O"           ' Source Last Column Letter/Number

    Const cFirstT As Variant = "D"          ' Target First Column Letter/Number

    Const cFirstRow As Long = 1             ' First Row Number
    Const cCriteria As Variant = "B"        ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cStrCriteria As String = "Plan"   ' Criteria String

    Dim lastRow As Long   ' Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long         ' Row Counter

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cFirstS).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = cFirstRow To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, cCriteria) = cStrCriteria Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, cFirstS), .Cells(i, cLastS)).Cut _
                        Destination:=.Cells(i, cFirstT)
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

### Copy ClearContents Version

```
Sub CopyClearContents()

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"      ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFirstS As Variant = "E"          ' Source First Column Letter/Number
    Const cLastS As Variant = "O"           ' Source Last Column Letter/Number

    Const cFirstT As Variant = "D"          ' Target First Column Letter/Number

    Const cFirstRow As Long = 1             ' First Row Number
    Const cCriteria As Variant = "B"        ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cStrCriteria As String = "Plan"   ' Criteria String

    Dim lastRow As Long   ' Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long         ' Row Counter

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cFirstS).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = cFirstRow To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, cCriteria) = cStrCriteria Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, cFirstS), .Cells(i, cLastS)).Copy _
                        Destination:=.Cells(i, cFirstT)
                .Cells(i, cLastS).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It works beautifully, thank you sir!!!
Have been struggling with this back and forth  for a few months….